# Taking the Log of a product sum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, actuarial-science

> Let $L = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} L_{i} = \Pi_{i}\lambda(t_{i})^{d_{i}}S(t_{i})$.

Can anyone point me to a source regarding the rules if one were to take the logarithm of $L$?

Comment: $log(a_1a_2...a_n)=log(a_1)+....+log(a_n)$

Comment: Where is this from?

Answer (score 0):

Using the rule $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$, we would have $\displaystyle \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^n L_i \right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(L_i)$.